# filtering results based on two ManyToOne relations in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-one

In the example below $type can be both 'brand' or 'category', and $slug will be either a brand or a category.

How would I approach this when I want to filter my results on a category and a brand at the same time?

```
    public function getGroupAction($slug, $type = null, $grouped = true)
{

    $group = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AudsurShopBundle:'.$type)
        ->findOneBy(array( 'name' => $slug ))
        ->getProducts();

    return $this->render('AudsurShopBundle:Default:productOverview.html.twig', array(
            'group' => $group
        )
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want to do, you have to use [Class table inheritance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance) with the system of a discriminator column.

For your example, create the following entity :

```
<?php

namespace ...

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discriminator", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"category" = "Category", "brand" = "Brand"})
 */
abstract class NameHolder
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

and then make your 2 entities inherit this class:

```
<?php

namespace ...;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * FirstChild
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Category extends NameHolder
{
    // all methods and properties except from the "name"
}
```

and:

```
<?php

namespace ...;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * FirstChild
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Brand extends NameHolder
{
    // all methods and properties except from the "name"
}
```

So now you can make a query like this:

```
$group = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AudsurShopBundle:NameHolder')
    ->findOneBy(array('name' => $slug))
    ->getProducts();
```

This will return an array collection with both `Brand` and `Category` entities.

However I am not sure a `NameHolder` class really makes sense. An other solution would be to make separate queries for both entities without changing any of your entities, but that's not what you seem to be looking for.